# Excel Chart range not updating

Tags: excel

I have created a chart which is dependent on a table of data, where the data range contracts and expands according to user input. There is a cell where the user can input how many months the chart range should be and the data table that the chart is connected to pulls the corresponding range of data from a different, master data table.

So my issue is that, when the chart data table contracts, the chart does not adjust. There is no issue with the chart data table expanding, only when the chart data table contracts, as it should be able to. The issue is even more strange because usually I can fiddle with a setting briefly and then the chart will update. For instance, i can go to Select Data on the chart and then hit cancel and the chart updates. Or I can change chart type to the same it already was, and the chart will update. So why is it that the chart does not initially update when the data in its range change?
Also, I would prefer to not use VBA on this due to the file sizes with which I am working. Is there a trick to getting this to work in Excel?

Below is an image of what I'm referring to:
[image]

Comment: I wish I could post a picture but I do not have enough points yet to do that

Comment: You can post a link to the picture and upload it elsewhere like imgur.com. It would probably help here.

Comment: Just posted a link to a picture. Hope that helps!